# How can I connect to MySQLi with variables from config.php file?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a MySQL & PHP based control panel for my community. And I've made a settings.php file with arrays with configs. I have class files for functions but there is MySQL function, which will not connect with data I've entered on settings.php..

I've tried other config file options, but none of them works...

on settings.php I have MySQL data like this:

```
$config['database']['host'] = "---"; 
$config['database']['user'] = "---";
$config['database']['password'] = "---";
$config['database']['database'] = "---";
```

And on userdata.php class file, where I'm trying to use those config variables I have:

```
$mysql = new mysqli($config['database']['host'], $config['database']['user'], $config['database']['password'], $config['database']['database']);
```

obviously, on userdata.php I have also required the settings.php..

I was expecting the output to be correct, but it shows only 'wrong MySQL data' errors...

Comment: If it says that the credentials are incorrect, then you need to provide the correct ones. So long as you're not getting any undefined variables/indexes, its with the actual values the issue lies.

Comment: Credentials are 100% correct.. I had them after `new mysqli` before.. I tried to include the settings file but now it shows some random sql data there, that i have no idea of.. I'm trying to figure this out. Thanks for the fast response tho.

Comment: I found out, that the userdata.php file is not using the settings.php file somehow.. that's why it shows some random data.. :/ 'localhost' etc.

Also I found this from my error log: `Undefined variable: config in nc/userdata.php on line 8`..

Comment: Could it be that you create the mysqli connection object inside of a function? If so, `$config` will not be accessible and you will need to pass it in into the function as parameter. And please don't make it a global variable instead :-). And I assume you are `require()`ing settings.php at the top of your main script before calling `mysqli()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with settings.php file like:

```
$config = array (
'db_host' => 'xxx',
'db_user' => 'xxx',
'db_pass' => 'xxx',
'db_database' => 'xxx'
```

and userdata.php like:

```
include 'settings.php';

$host = $config['db_host'];
$user = $config['db_user'];
$pass = $config['db_pass'];
$database = $config['db_database'];

$mysql = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way in `connection.php` file

```
<?php
include_once("path/config.php");

function OpenCon()
{
  $dbhost = $config['database']['host'];
  $dbuser = $config['database']['user'];
  $dbpass = $config['database']['password'];
  $db = $config['database']['db'];

  $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". 
  $conn -> error);

  return $conn;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it tried connecting to 'localhost' somehow.. error shows `@'localhost'`.. :/